# Iterate through characters in a String in Swift

Tags: string, swift, iteration

I want to iterate through a String with condition to skip 2 or more characters in 1 iteration. An example code in C++

```
// str = "123" 
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(), i++) {
    if (str[i] == '2') {
        // do something
        i++;
    }
    // do something
}
```

My Swift version is like this, but after the iteration finishs, there is an error saying:

> "fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String"

```
// str = "123" 
for var index = str.startIndex; index != str.endIndex; index = index.advancedBy(1) {
    if (str[index] == "2") {
        // do something
        index = index.advancedBy(1)
    }
    // do something
}
```

I guess this is the place I got wrong, `"index != str.endIndex"`

How to fix it or any alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: `advancedBy(i)` should probably be `advancedBy(1)`

Comment: Thank you @MartinR that was a typo

Comment: Note that your C++ code also has a flaw: If the last character is '2' then `i` is incremented *beyond* the string size.